# SCTP: any cross-platform library?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sctp

I'm investigating [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) protocol. Its features look attractive. What I worry is its support from community. Is there any good cross-platform (at least Linux and Windows) C++ (or at least C) SCTP library? Does it support async methods?

Comment: I am not sure if you are willing to pay for this library but CCPU/Radisys has a platform independent library for SCTP. Their libraries works on win,linux,solaris and vx works. You can check it out at (http://www.ccpu.com/trillium-protocol-software-products/all-protocols-list/sctp-stream-control-transmission-protocol/)

Comment: I haven't found their prices, do you know how much it costs?

Comment: No. I guess you will have to send a mail at sales@ccpu.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how well tested/working this is (never got to use it myself), but I looked at http://code.halssoftware.com/index.php/p/boostasiosctp/source/tree/master/boost a while ago. Let me know if that does anything for you.

Comment: +1: great, I didn't expect to find **Boost.Asio** adapter, will have a look at it

Comment: found [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/3964). seems `SCTP` adapter for `Boost.Asio` is not ready and nobody knows when it will be

Comment: Ah: it looked incomplete, but hadn't dug deeper. Well, you may want to try http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html instead then. It claims *nix/*BSD/Windows support, but that one really is a wild guess on my part as to whether it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Update:
A cross platform userland stack [link](http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/sctp-user-land-stack.html)

Exists and is actively maintained at Münster University of Applied Sciences

Answer (score 2):

Linux and Solaris both have robust Kernel implementations but Windows is dragging it's feet somewhat. There is a project to add one http://www.bluestop.org/SctpDrv/. If you try to run your own SCTP implementation alongside Kernel ones then you are likely to encounter issues with the two stacks interfering with each other.

The Kernel stacks offer comparable sockets interfaces so your application is portable across Linux / Solaris.

Regards