# Controlling your phone from laptop

Tags: java, android, p2p

**Idea**: create a remote control for your android phone.

**Why**: I like listening music on my phone in a dock station with speakers connected. Now sometimes I want to turn the volume up/down, change the song, etc. So I need to unlock the phone, locate app that is playing music (Music player, internet radio app, etc.). Sometimes I manage to undock the phone or just mess something up and generally this s*cks.

So I would like to control my phone (on a data connection, not wifi) from the laptop (on wifi).

I had investigated couple of approaches and would like to get some recommendations on them:

1. *Use XMPP*. This is nice as there a lots of free XMPP services I can use. Two libraries (both based on smack) that I tried work just fine (Flow [aSmack port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions/5487854#5487854) and Beem [smack port](http://www.beem-project.com/projects/beem)). I could automatically create new user on device and present some id/password combination that I (user) would enter on a desktop side to link both devices.
2. *Use [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com/)*. Should be the next *real deal* but could be an overkill. I would imagine running a rendezvous&relay server somewhere (need to get hosting to work around firewall/NAT) and creating a peer group protected with password. Use device unique id and password (withing group) to link to the desktop application. (A great eBook explaining p2p and JXTA can be downloaded from [here](http://www.brendonwilson.com/projects/jxta-book/)).
3. *Use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)*. Could be the answer, but notification delivery sometimes can take more then couple of seconds to deliver and there would be no feedback mechanism.

So far first solutions looks like a lot easier choice. Create custom extension or just create chat between both endpoints and use that for relaying commands/messages. But I wonder if I would be abusing XMPP system?

JXTA sounds great, but from all the reading I done it is apparent that it is designed for group communication and service sharing and not a solution for connecting two endpoints.

What do you guys think? I welcome all suggestions too.

**UPDATE** I do not want to remote to a phone and interactively control it. I want to establish a connection (socket connection) between laptop and phone even if both of them are on different networks secured behind firewalls, routers. With this I could define a protocol to issue commands to the phone (lower volume, mute, start app, etc.).

**UPDATE 2** I'm giving JXTA a shot. It is a nice solution but lack of documentation is a bit of a downer. Got VPS FreeBSD server to test RDV/relay side of things. I keep updating this question further as it may be helpful for others.

**UPDATE 3** Some more reading:

- [How to make two android devices to communicate through TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526830/how-to-make-two-android-devices-to-communicate-through-tcp/6025771)
- [Connection between two computers without opening ports using a third computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327728/communication-between-two-computers-without-opening-ports-using-a-third-compute/7374426)

**UPDATE 4** 
So far I did not have enough time to further continue my project. I did find an interesting [project](http://ice.in.htwg-konstanz.de/index.html). At the moment project owners are re-writing their library, you can track their progress [here](https://github.com/htwg/UCE).

Comment: is it possible to utilize your laptop's bluetooth? haven't thought about or tried it before, until i read your question.

Comment: It would work, but I do not want to use bluetooth. My idea is that if I could use network to achieve this kind of remote, then later on it would be possible to augment developed solution to all kinds of cool usages.

Comment: Use C2DM with a custom controlling app? Wouldn't be too difficult or set up SMS if you want near-realtime

Comment: @Joe I have never dealt with SMS gateways. Wouldn't it cost a fortune?

Comment: It depends. If it's for a personal pet project you can keep an eye on SMS costs really easily. C2DM still costs but has a free quota but less reliable

Comment: There are already a number of competing apps doing this sort of thing, have you checked if any of them are open source?

Comment: @Thor84no The ones I checked use WiFi for direct connect and a "proxy" server to relay all data on mobile data connection. In my case I want to be able to make a direct connection from phone to PC. I do not mind using server for initial discovery. Do you have some particular project/app in mind?

Comment: @Audrius I can't remember which apps I used, but there were 2 I used around a year ago that basically just start a web server on your phone and you connect to it however you want (wifi, or USB with localhost forwarding usually, but also potentially 3g). I might see if I can dig up the names.

Answer (score 1):

why do not you try installing [VNC server](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=en) on machine and then use VNC client on laptop to access mobile

Comment: Can you issue commands through VNC that then can be intercepted by client o perform some operations?

Comment: Thing is I do not want to have an interactive remote connection. And this doesn't solve firewall/router traverse issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile Shell (Mosh)](http://mosh.mit.edu/) maybe just the tool you are looking for. I have been looking for a good project to use Mosh, your idea seems pretty interesting :)

Comment: It's a shell, I would still need to solve NAT traversal issue. Thanks for an interesting link though.